# RGI output filename does not match snakefile output filename

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

The problem is:

A software called "RGI" will automatically append `.txt` as suffix to the output file. So if my `sampleID` is `7`. Then the actual RGI output file will be `7.txt`, which is different from the output file (`7`) defind in the snakefile rule. And snakemake will report errors like `Job Missing files after 20 seconds`. However, RGI still appends `.txt` as suffix even if you have preset a suffix (and the actual output file will look like `7.txt.txt`).

How can I solve the problem?
The following is a part of my code:

```
rule rgi:
output:
    cardTxt = "{sampleId}/annotation/rgi/{sampleId}"
input:
    faa = rules.prokka.output.faa,
    cardDb = config['rgi']['cardDb']
shell:
    """
    rgi load -i {input.cardDb}
    rgi main -i {input.faa} -t protein -o {output.cardTxt} --include_loose --clean
    """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the `.txt` prefix from the output filename before passing it to `rgi`. I do this here using bash string manipulation but you can do it in other ways:

```
rule rgi:
    input:
        faa = rules.prokka.output.faa,
        cardDb = config['rgi']['cardDb'],
    output:
        cardTxt = "{sampleID}/annotation/rgi/{sampleID}.txt",
    shell:
        """
        card=${{{output.cardTxt}%.txt}}

        rgi load -i {input.cardDb}
        rgi main -i {input.faa} -t protein -o $card --include_loose --clean
        """
```

(I assume you want `.txt` to be part of the output filename. I.e. you are ok with `7.txt`)

Comment: Your answer gave me a hint, and I tried this way for the covenience:
`shell:
"""
 rgi load -i {input.cardDb}
 rgi main -i {input.faa} -t protein -o {wildcards.sampleId}/annotation/rgi/{wildcards.sampleId} --include_loose --clean
"""
`
Although it may not be the best solution.